# how to give url a unique id in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I want give particular unique id in my url, 
like at the end of url **"?id=smtb"** should be included...

as I am not knowing which code to be used in order to convert below url

```
www.mylink.com/page.php
```

into

```
www.mylink.com/page.php?id=smtb
www.mylink.com/page.php?id=sea
```

so that I can able to store in my database

Comment: What's the relation between `id` and `p`?

Comment: sorry mate, but i want someting like www.mylink.com/page.php?id=smtb

Comment: Rewrite your question and make it more clear.

Comment: What is actual problem here?

Comment: ok sorry, let me rewrite entire explantion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create uniq id's with this following function in PHP.

```
$up_id = uniqid();
```

If you just want your random id in Just the letters like string format.

You can uset that following function definied.

```
function generateRandomString($length = 5) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```

You can get the link with linking like `<a href="page.php?id=<?php echo $up_id; ?>">here you go</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Contact Form

```
<form method="GET" action="process.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="p" id="p" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" />
</form>
```

process.php

```
$pageid = $_GET['p'];
```

When you click the link, you wil get something like:

www.abc.de/process.php?p=123123
this part makes no sense for me tho:

```
<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>
```

probably its this:

```
<?php echo $id ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you are looking for a way to generate a unique (numeric) id for each form you submit?

The first thing that comes to mind is to use a time function, which technically could result in duplicates, but in practice will be safe unless you have over 1000 requests per second.

```
$id = microtime(true) * 10000;
```

this snippet will produce a number similar to: **13966142246941**

As for including it in your form, I'm guessing that @Xatenev's answer will suffice.

```
<?php echo $id ?>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: sorry Mate, I want to generate unique id for my links which are already there.....

Comment: then just tack on the $id to the end of your link

Comment: but how to give that id like "?id-smtb"